# Copying a postgres database from one server to another

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres database with a number of schemas and a number of tables within each of the schemas, and the tables have a bunch of foreign key relationships with one another.  All I want to do is copy everything from one server to another server, essentially creating a copy of the first server.  At this point, I don't care if I have to knock either or both servers completely out of commission while I do this.

I can't figure out a way to just copy everything in the first database directly into the second database.  I tried pg_dump and pg_restore but the restore violated a bunch of the foreign constraints, and therefore didn't restore properly.  I have read that you can do a data only restore that will eliminate all of the data, disable constraints while the data is loading, and then re-enable the constraints when the data has been loaded, but this assumes the source and the target database have the same table structure, which they do not.  If there was a way to dump just the schema and just the data, I would imagine that this would work, but I have not found a way to do that either.

Comment: You probably want to use a binary dump.   If that is still not working for you (it should), you can copy over the data files using "hot standby" mode.  See sections 24.2 and 25 of the PostgreSQL Administrator's Guide.

Comment: did you try setting constraints to deferrable mode to avoid the foreign constraints violation?

Comment: @BadZen That's not a "binary dump", btw, that's just a copy of the whole PostgreSQL install. (I'd expect a "binary dump" to be something still done with `pg_dump`, writing binary instead of text-file data for `COPY`. It took me a while to figure out what you meant). You also don't use hot standby, that's quite separate. You want `pg_basebackup -X stream`, or if you're getting fancy, WAL archiving and `pg_start_backup()`, `rsync`, `pg_stop_backup()`.

Comment: @zelinka Notably missing from this question are **the error messages**, the exact commands you ran, the PostgreSQL version(s) in use, etc.

Comment: @CraigRinger - Sorry, I should have been clearer - there are two things I'm suggesting.  One is the binary pg_dump with "custom" format (-c switch), the other is the file based copy.  In the latter case, by the way, you don't copy the entire installation, just a subset of the data files.  The citation I gave has details.

Comment: @BadZen If you don't copy the whole install with a basebackup approach then you'll get an unusable DB. You can exclude `pg_xlog` only if you have WAL achiving enabled. That's it. You certainly can't just copy one database, for example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to take a database `mydb` on `server1` and copy it to `mydb` on `server2`, *completely replacing all contents of `mydb` on `server2`*, dump with something like:

```
pg_dump -Fc -f mydb.dump -h server1 mydb
```

then restore with:

```
dropdb -h server2 mydb
createdb -h server2 -T template0 mydb
pg_restore -d mydb -h server2 mydb.dump
```

This will:

- `DROP` database `mydb` on `server2`, **completely and permanently destroying all data in `mydb` on `server2`**
- Re-`CREATE` database `mydb` on `server2` from a totally empty template
- Restore the copy of `mydb` on `server1` into `server2`

Another option is to use `pg_restore --clean` without the drop and create. That'll drop all tables then re-create them. I prefer to drop the whole DB and get a clean one instead.

Comment: I'm assuming `server1` in the first line of code should read `server`

Answer (score 3):

**Scenario: To cop Db1 from PC1 to PC2**

**In PC1:**

Run PgAdmin

Right CLick on the Db1 >Backup.

Give a Filename and Save.

Copy the saved file from the PC to another PC.

**In PC2:**

Right Click on Database> Create> Assign Filename "Db1" (same name as in PC1)

Right Click Db1> Restore>select the copied file (if file is not getting displayed, click show all files)

Done!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do a "custom" format backup, and then on a blank database at the new place, do a restore. That has worked for me in the past. But if you do a plain text backup, you're going to get the errors you've been getting.

Comment: I use pgAdmin UI to do these tasks.

Comment: pgAdmin has a horrible interface to backup/restore (or at least did as of last year at some point) - consider doing them by hand, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

This too will work

pg_dump -Fd -f dump -h serverip -U smartcare

pg_restore -d smartcare -h localhost -U postgres dump

dump and restore db